# Reloading View and ViewModel

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm a newbie in web and particularly Single Page Application.
I have a main menu where I invoke procedure HomePage which load a `Div class="PhotoStack"` and create ViewModel `ScatteredGallaryMVVM`:

```
function HomePage() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Home",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var contentObject = $(data)[0];

        $(".MainContent").empty();
        $(".MainContent").append(contentObject);

        if (!window.hasOwnProperty("scatteredGallaryMVVM")) {
            window.scatteredGallaryMVVM = new ScatteredGallaryMVVM();
            ko.applyBindings(window.scatteredGallaryMVVM, $(".MainContent")[0]);
        }

        window.scatteredGallaryMVVM.FillGallary();

    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    });


function ScatteredGallaryMVVM() {

   var self = this;
   self.Products = ko.observableArray();

   self.FillGallary = function () {

       $.ajax({
           url: '/Products/GetProducts',
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            self.Products(data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        });

};  

 <div class="PhotoStack" data-bind="foreach: Products">
    <figure class="PhotoStackFigure">
        <a class="PhotoStackHyperlink">
         <img class="PhotoStackImage" data-bind="attr: { src: ImageUrl }"></img>
        </a>
        <figcaption>
           <p data-bind="text: Object.Name"/>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
 </div>
```

INDEX MAIN PAGE

```
 <html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <title>Index</title>
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Site")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="MainCanvas">
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/Index/MainMenu.cshtml")
         <div class="MainContent">
         </div>
     </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

When I invoke `HomePage` for the first time it works well. But when I invoke `HomePage` again It doesn't work (div has 1 figure without any data although I get 8 objects from a server).
PS: excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 0):

see that you do an ajax call. After an ajax call there is no postback, so your browser does not know about changes in your view model To accomplish that you need to update the dom elements of your page either in the success method of ajax call (done in your case) or using a binding library like knockoutjs or angular.

EDIT:

As you are already using knockout. It does not make sense to manipulate dom elements in the ajax success as you did by removing and injecting html into your $(".MainContent").

Create a ViewModel for your MainContent and apply bindings to it. Doing so you no longer need to manipulate dom elemens. Your ajax should be as clean as possible only applying the binding and mapping you response to your ViewModel.

Comment: Hi. I did't understand your answer.  As you can see in this case I already use binding library knockout and it works well in first procedure invoking. I think the problem is in deleting DIV in .MainContent and inserting DIV again in . MainContent when i invoke the procedure for for the second time. But how can I avoid it (re inserting) if i do SPA?

Comment: You are right @MadBoy I made confusion, I'm sorry. So, the problem is, when you need to manipulate dom elements inside your ajax success method, means that your knockout view models /  mvc view models are not well structured. MainCOntent should also have its observables (parent viewmodel).  You know what I mean right?

Comment: not really)  I just have added index (main) page (html) in question. Should I create main ViewModel and add others ViewModels as properties? Can you show me?

Comment: I updated my answer, try following this example, is easy to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/EYueU/

Comment: I have to remove and insert HTML in MainContent @Daniel Groh because it's SPA and accordingly there might be different content there like list of products or card form or home page or about page or something else (it depends on what button in main menu you click). Your example work well but It does't work in my case.

Comment: be careful this is not a SPA concept, you don't do that because it's SPA, you do that because you need, in my projects I have never ever manipulated UI elements when working knockout. Nevertheless, if possible, try to run a sample on jsfiddle with fake data and then I would be able to help you buddy